# Firebase And Firestore User management in SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I want to build an app that handles authentication with firebase and the cloud storage part with Firestore. How should I automatically create a user inside the "users" collection when I a user registers and also how should the user struct fetching be done when the user just logged in the app.

I insert only the functions

I have a class authenticationViewModel:

```
ObservableObject{
    @Published var user:User?

    func SignInWithEmailAndPassword() async -> Bool {
        //login user account
        authenticationState = .Authenticating
        do{
            let authResult = try await Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)
            print("User \(authResult.user.uid) signed in")
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
            errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
            authenticationState = .UnAuthenticated
            return false
        }
        authenticationState = .Authenticated
        errorMessage=""
        return true
    }
    
    func SignUpwithEmailAndPassword() async -> Bool {
        //create new user account
        authenticationState = .Authenticating
        do{
            let authResult = try await Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)
            print("User \(authResult.user.uid) signed in")
        }
        catch{
            print(error)
            errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
            authenticationState = .UnAuthenticated
            return false
        }
        authenticationState = .Authenticated
        errorMessage=""
        return true
    }

}
```

and a class called userDataManagment:

```
ObservableObject{
    @Published var sessionUser: CustomUser?

    init(){
        getUserData(documentID: Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "")
    }
    func getUserData(documentID: String){
        let docRef=db.collection("users").document(documentID)
        docRef.getDocument(as: CustomUser.self){ result in
            switch result{
            case.success(let user):
                //User was succsesfully initialized
                self.sessionUser = user
                self.errorMessage = nil
            case.failure(let error):
                //user could not be instantieted
                self.errorMessage="Error decoding document: \(error.localizedDescription)"
            }
        }
    }
    
    func updateUserData(user: CustomUser){
        if let id=user.id{
            let docRef=db.collection("user").document(id)
            do{
                try docRef.setData(from: user)
            }catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func addUser(user: User){
        let collectionRef=db.collection("users")
        do{
            let newDocReference = try collectionRef.addDocument(from: self.sessionUser)
            print("User was added succseully")
        }catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't figure out how to properly manage this situation so for now I'm just using a testUser that is hardCoded so that I can create the proper views for my app

Comment: Where are you calling `addUser` function from? Have you tried calling it right after sign up and passing the user UID as document ID? See [Set a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#swift_1) section of the documentation.

Comment: For the moment addUser is not being called anywhere. I wanted to call it right after sign up but I don't exactly understand how should I create my custom user with the fields from authentication process, since I have two separate classes for authentication and data management.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this simple provider:

```
final class UserProfileProvider: ObservableObject {
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func createProfile(profile: UserProfile) async throws {
        try await db.collection("profiles").document(profile.uid).setData(from: profile, merge: true)
    }
}

extension FirebaseFirestore.DocumentReference {
    func setData<T: Encodable>(from: T, merge: Bool = false) async throws {
        let encoder = Firestore.Encoder()
        let data = try encoder.encode(from)
        try await setData(data, merge: merge)
    }
}
```

and your `SignInWithEmailAndPassword` can look like this:

```
func SignInWithEmailAndPassword() async -> Bool {
    //login user account
    authenticationState = .Authenticating
    do{
        let authResult = try await Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password)
        try await userProfileProvider.createProfile(profile: .init(uid: UUID().uuidString,
                                                                   firstName: firstName,
                                                                   lastName: lastName,
                                                                   countryCode: countryCode ?? "AT"))
        print("User \(authResult.user.uid) signed in")
    }
    catch{
        print(error)
        errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
        authenticationState = .UnAuthenticated
        return false
    }
    authenticationState = .Authenticated
    errorMessage=""
    return true
}
```

of course you pass your User; mine has 4 fields (firstName, lastName, country).